# Logging to MongoDB from python

Tags: python, logging, mongodb

i want to log some information into mongodb using python . i found 2 libraries mongodblog and log4mongo for python. any idea which one is better ? or any other library which is better than these ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you use MongoDB for logging, the concern is the **lock contention** by high write throughputs. Although MongoDB's insert is fire-and-forget style by default, calling a lot of insert() causes a heavy write lock contention. This could affect the application performance, and prevent the readers to aggregate / filter the stored logs.

One solution might be using the **log collector framework** such as [Fluentd](http://fluentd.org/), [Logstash](http://logstash.net/), or [Flume](http://flume.apache.org/). These daemons are supposed to be launched at every application nodes, and takes the logs from app processes.

[image: Fluentd plus MongoDB]

They buffer the logs and **asynchronously** writes out the data to other systems like MongoDB / PostgreSQL / etc. The write is done by **batches**, so it's a lot more efficient than writing directly from apps. This link describes how to put the logs into Fluentd from Python program.

- [Fluentd: Data Import from Python Applications](http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/python)

Here's some tutorials about MongoDB + Fluentd.

- [Fluentd + MongoDB: The Easiest Way to Log Your Data Effectively](http://blog.10gen.com/post/27619817959/fluentd-mongodb-the-easiest-way-to-log-your-data) on 10gen blog
- [Fluentd: Store Apache Logs into MongoDB](http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/apache-to-mongodb)

Comment: the `Fluentd: Data Import from Python Applications`  and  `Fluentd: Store Apache Logs into MongoDB`  are 404 already.

Comment: why **prevent the readers to aggregate / filter the stored logs** ?    This action could be done when the logging is finished or still in progress right?

Answer (score 2):

No need to use a logging library. Use pymongo and do the following:

1. create a different database from your application database (it can be on the same machine) to avoid problems with high write throughput hogging the lock that the rest of your application may need.
2. if there is a ton of logging to be done, consider using a capped collection
3. if you need to be analyzing the log as it occurs, write another script that uses a tailable cursor: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-tailable-cursor/

The upshot is that all of your logging needs can be taken care of with a few lines of code. Again, no need to complicate your code base by introducing extra dependencies when a bit of code will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by other users here, it is quite simple to log directly using pymongo:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pymongo import ASCENDING
import datetime

client = MongoClient()
db = client.my_logs
log_collection = db.log
log_collection.ensure_index([("timestamp", ASCENDING)])  


def log(msg):
    """Log `msg` to MongoDB log"""
    entry = {}
    entry['timestamp'] = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    entry['msg'] = msg
    log_collection.insert(entry)

log('Log messages like this')
```

You might want to experiment by replacing the `_id` with the timestamp, just remember that `_id` has to be unique.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **`Mongolog`** or **`Log4Mongo`**. Both of them have log appender for python logging package. You can easily instantiate your log handler (mongo log handler) and add it (the handler)  to your logger. Rest of the thing will be handled out of the box. Both of them also support capped collection (could be useful in case of huge records of logs(specially junk longs) )

Log4Mongo : https://pypi.org/project/log4mongo/

Github page : https://github.com/log4mongo/log4mongo-python

MongoLog : https://pypi.org/project/mongolog/#description

Github page : https://github.com/puentesarrin/mongodb-log

Answer (score 0):

Here is the author of one of the libraries. I can't say much about the other library.
I agree that for really a lot of logs you should not necessarily use mongodb directly (the accepted answer does a fair job of explaining what should be used.
However, for medium size (medium in the sense of traffic and amount of logs) applications where a complex setup might be undesirable you can use `BufferedMongoHandler`, this [logging class](https://github.com/log4mongo/log4mongo-python/blob/fc23cb51eed87930f184835d8c119d3029946925/log4mongo/handlers.py#L173) is designed to solve exactly that locking problem.
It does that by collecting the messages and writing them periodically instead of immidieatly. Take a look at the code, it is pretty straight forward.
IMO, if you already use mongodb, and you feel comfortable with it, it's an OK solution.